# Tell if an instance is pointed to by other variables?

Tags: c#, reflection, garbage-collection

This is a longshot but...

I understand there is a way to tell if variable A (var1, var2...., varX) points to instance of class by using `Equals`:

```
        List<string> _mainInstance = new();
        var var1 = _mainInstance;
        var var2 = _mainInstance;
        var var3 = _mainInstance;

        //I understand how to tell if variable points to _mainInstance
        if (var1.Equals(_mainInstance))
        {
            //It does because it points by reference
        }

        //I want to check if any variable still point to _mainInstance
        if (!_mainInstance.HasOthersPointingToIt())
        {
            //Safe to delete _mainInstance
        }
```

I don't know at design time how many pointers to _myInstance there will be. I want to check if my `_mainInstance` has any variables still pointing to it every so often. I thought maybe reflection or garbage collection but all my research there is coming up with nothing.

Is there a way to examine a variable (in this case an instance of a class) and tell if anything else (variables, properties of a class instance) still point to it?

**Edit:**
@GuruStron asks what is the underlying problem I am trying to solve?

Answer: I have a parent/child "tree" that I need to keep track of. That in itself is pretty easy. My difficulty is that the tree has blocks that have a single definition and that definition gets reused.

In the graph below it shows the top tree with stars. The stars represents pointers to block definitions. Below that on the left are the actual block definitions.

[image]

The the block definition gets substituted and the final tree looks like this:

[image]

When a block pointer is deleted I need to make sure that nothing else is pointing to that block definition and delete the block definition when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Side note: technically to check *references* ("if variable **points** to _mainInstance") you should use `ReferenceEquals`: `if (ReferenceEquals(var1, _mainInstance)) { ... }`. In case of `List<T>` `Equals` uses `ReferenceEquals`, but in general case it doesn't hold

Comment: Note the the GC does the opposite of what you're asking for. It finds everything that *can* be reached from any of the current roots and everything else is considered garbage. It can't declare *one* object garbage, it doesn't track its individual references.

Comment: What do you mean by **delete** - "Safe to **delete** `_mainInstance`", please?

Comment: You can use WeakReferences to keep a track of something and be able to check whether it was collected in the meantime. But that's only useful if you don't need to interact with the object once all other references disappear. It would help to know what you *would* plan to do if you *could* perform this check.

Comment: _" I want to check if my _mainInstance has any variables still pointing to it every so often. "_ Why? What is an underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: `_mainInstance` is a list.  What does it even mean to delete it?  The GC will delete the memory used by the list automatically when it is no longer used.  What are you planning to do?  If you want to clear the items, then don't bother, you're just making things worse by preventing the GC from being able to collect it for even longer while you go through trying to "clean it up".

Comment: So the problem presumably is that you have some "external to the tree" collection of these block definitions. It seems like `Dictionary<string,WeakReference<BlockDefinition>>` is what you're looking for (assuming you use `string` as the key to locate block definitions in this collection). And then you still let GC handle the actual cleanup of objects and you can (at your leisure) prune the dictionary of entries that no longer hold a reference to a block definition.

Comment: (And of course, substitute in Immutable or Concurrent collection in the above, if required)